Why can't Windows tell if my laptop's internal microphone is unplugged?
I had to do a repair on my Lenovo Legion 7's hinge and display.
During the course of this the microphone that is below the display became unplugged. It took me ages to work out this was the problem as Windows gave me no indication that there was any fault. The device said there was no hardware fault.
Shouldn't Windows be able to tell if there is a problem as fundamental as the microphone board being unplugged?

Is there a schematic available for the Lenovo Legion 7 which shows the components on the microphone board, and signals used in connecting to the motherboard? Without such details are unable to give a specific answer about if the hardware can indicate to the Windows software if the microphone board is connected or not.

Not that i'm aware of

Each PC model has it's own hardware and firmware for sensing microphone/headphone insertion.
For example, on this Dell from which I'm answering, now, the jack is configured to act as headphone, headset with mic, or microphone through software. When a device is plugged in, a dialog is shown to select the function.

On an old Toshiba I use, there is no detection of jack insertion on the PC: a physical switch connects the external phones/speaker and disconnects the internal speakers when a plug is inserted.
It's not Windows alone that determines the behavior for that jack, but the manufacturer's hardware and firmware, and its software that pops up that dialog... or not.

I read the question about an internal connection between the laptop motherboard and microphone board which wasn't re-connected following a repair, rather than sensing what is external device is connected to a jack socket. This doesn't invalidate the answer, but thought worth mentioning.

Without access to the schematics of the microphone board, potentially the motherboard, and maybe the source code of the various firmwares as well as the driver, it is impossible to know why Windows cannot detect the microphone board being disconnected.
However, it is possible to make some educate guesses. So, here's a couple of reasons I could imagine why Windows cannot detect the microphone board being disconnected:

Lenovo did not put a sensor in the connector, on the microphone board, or on the motherboard to detect this.
Maybe there is a sensor, but Lenovo did not connect it. (It is possible, for example, that the microphone board is a third-party component which comes with such a sensor, but Lenovo chose to not implement it into their design.)
Maybe there is a sensor and it is connected, but the firmware has not been programmed to read it.
Maybe the firmware is programmed to read it, but it is not reporting the status to the driver.
Maybe the firmware is reporting the status to the driver, but the driver is not programmed to react to it.
Maybe the firmware is reporting the status to the driver and the driver is programmed to react to it, but the driver is not reporting the status to Windows.
Maybe there is a bug in Windows.
Maybe there is a bug in the driver.
Maybe there is a bug in the firmware.
Maybe there is a bug in the sensor.
Maybe there is a bug in the board design.
Maybe there is a bug in the wiring.
Maybe whatever disconnected the cable also broke the wiring of the sensor.
Maybe Windows simply has no way of reporting a microphone daughterboard not being connected.

Personally, my money is on #1: why would Lenovo waste money, resources, space, and power budget on a sensor that checks whether a cable that isn't even meant to be unplugged (except during a repair, which is presumably performed by a qualified service technician or a reasonably qualified power user) is plugged in?

i just assumed that there would be some sort of back and forth between the disconnected board and the rest of the computer as part of its usual functionality, and that, if it didn't recieve this it would know something is up.
